# How to dynamically pass parameter to the RPM during installation

Tags: dynamic, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

We are in need to dynamically pass a variable during RPM installation and capture it in the spec file to  trigger a script in %post

Following is the command
**RPM Install Command**
sudo rpm -Uvh --force abc.noarch.rpm --define '_ip 10.1.2.4' --define 'version 3'

```
**abc.spec**

Name:       abc
Version:    1
Release:    1.0
Summary:    Test

%{!?_ip: %define _ip 0.0.0.0 }

%{!?_version: %define _version 0 }

%post 

echo "ip:::: %{_ip}"
echo "VESION:::: %{_version}"
```

So when I run the RPM with the above command , I get the following output.

[root@test solution]$ sudo rpm -Uvh --force abc.noarch.rpm --define '_ip 10.1.2.4' --define 'version 3'
Preparing... ################################# [100%]

Updating / installing...

1:abc ################################# [ 50%]

ip:::: 0.0.0.0

VESION:::: 0

Though i pass a different value in the CLI command , I still see that the argument which I pass is not been captured in the spec file.

Need inputs on how to capture the values which im passing the CLI .

Answer (score 1):

The option `--define` defines macro. Macros are evaluated when building an RPM from SRC.RPM using rpmbuild. The binary (does not matter if arch or noarch) package has every macro already expanded. Even the %bindir etc.

The RPM ecosystem was designed as non-interactive. This is a big difference from the DEB ecosystem when questions can be raised using debconf.

You cannot workaround it. You cannot ask even by directly reading STDIN as rpm close this descriptor before executing scriptlets.

The best practice is to use configuration files. E.g. `/etc/abc/ip.conf`. And:

1. either instruct user to manualy (or using Ansible) alter that file and store their correct data
2. or do NOT distribute `/etc/abc/ip.conf` in main `abc` package and instead require `abc-config`. And then create one or more config packages which will be like:

```
Package: abc-testing-config
Provides: abc-config
...
%files
/etc/abc/ip.conf
```

And you then instruct users to install `abc abc-test-config`. Or it can be `abc abc-EMEA-config` etc....

Comment: Also tag the file as `%config` so you don't break verification.